# Displaying html via angular

Tags: html, angularjs, ngsanitize

I'm trying to show the html that has been encoded. but this doesn't seem to work.
input is via:

```
&lt;h1&gt;Some header&lt;/h1&gt;
```

and it shows:

<h1>Some header</h1>

But I want it to render the html; but as shown in the following pen; it just show the source html

this is my current controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('&lt;h1&gt;Some header&lt;/h1&gt;');
});
```

with the following html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/cskiwi/pen/PqXdOa

Comment: Then decode the html and set it to binded property...What is the problem?

Comment: @Engineer then my question is how to decode it

Comment: Can you please post code as well as codepen link - not everyone has time to go web browsing and you'll get more response I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decode the html, you can use this trick:

```
var encodedHtml = '&lt;h1&gt;Some header&lt;/h1&gt;';
var decodedHtml = angular.element('<div>').html(encodedHtml).text();
```

Then apply to your property:

```
$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(decodedHtml);
```

Comment: I've found something similar, but isn't strange that you need to create a div in order to show html?

Comment: @Kiwi No, it is not. Otherwise you need to use `String.replace` method. And take acount all special symbols, like `&amp;`,`&lt;`, etc..

Answer (score 0):

**You will have to sanitize your html data/string :**

I have the same problem before some time , then i created a filter for this problem, You can use this filter to do sanitize your html code:

```
app.filter("sanitize", ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(htmlCode) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
    }
}]);
```

in html you can use like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="businesses.oldTimings | sanitize"></div>
```

businesses.oldTimings  is $scope variable having description of strings or having strings with html tags , $scope.businesses.oldTimings  is the part of particular controller that you are using for that html.

see in the snapshot:

[image]

**you can use limitHtml filter to do the same:**

```
app.filter('limitHtml', function() {
    return function(text, limit) {
        var changedString = String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '  ');
        var length = changedString.length;
        return changedString.length > limit ? changedString.substr(0, limit - 1) : changedString;
    }
});
```

**Then you can add bothe filter in your html like that:**

```
<p class="first-free-para" ng-bind-html="special.description| limitHtml : special.description.length | sanitize">
```

**Hope it will work for you.**

Answer (score -1):

Check this codepen please
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGmaWR

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

 myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.trustedHtml = '<h1>Some header</h1>';
 });
```

[Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: that doesn't answer my question, it just says here's a working example of a different input ....

Comment: Your question says "displaying html via angular" and my answer does exactly that. And in your body you say "I want to render the html"

Comment: That's my title indeed, then in the question itself I explain what my input is and what I want it should be. So my title suggests what the questions says ...